# How to call Chromecast API from another Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromecast, google-cast

I developed an Chrome extension using  "panel" style background page, and I want to launch the Chromecast application when a "launch cast" button on the "panel" is clicked. My understanding is that the chrome.cast.requestSession should be called to the Chromecast extension, but in this case seems the call failed and the session cannot be established. Does the Chromecast Extension support API call from another extension?

Comment: Would it work to have a content script whose job it is to request the Chromecast session, and then have your background page, when the cast icon is clicked on, send a message to your content script for it to start the session request process? That way the content script would be running in the context of the page.